# Ubuntu very slow at start and general after upgrade amd64 version

Tags: dell, swap

I update from 18.04 to 20.04 it was slow before the update what can I do to run better.I mean when I start the computer its take like 5min to load to login screen after login it takes up to 10 min to start working properly I open firefox and the webpages load like in the 1998 load time too big I didn't mention if I run some program.Currently i hava 4GB RAM.Any suggestion will be welcomed.If need to post some output from command I am ready to do it.
Ubuntu version

```
5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Laptop data

```
description: Laptop
product: Latitude E6410
vendor: Dell Inc.
version: 0001
serial: 77031P1
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
```

/etc/fstab output:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=612c62a6-d6b0-41c6-b970-4de20dc9034d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=17AC-6200  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Also I have different user account and I lost it somehow I forgot the password and I done some changes from boot menu I make a new account and all my old data was lose and the hdd size is less now I think the rest is locked in the another account.

```
/0/8/0.0.0       /dev/sda    disk           160GB WDC WD1600BEKT-7
/0/8/0.0.0/1                 volume         512MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/8/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2   volume         148GiB Extended partition
/0/8/0.0.0/2/5   /dev/sda5   volume         148GiB EXT4 volume
```

free -h:

```
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3,8Gi       2,5Gi       150Mi        57Mi       1,2Gi       1,0Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi       8,0Mi       2,0Gi
```

Comment: Output of `free -h` will be helpful

Comment: done I post it now

Comment: Ohk found the problem :)

Comment: Lemme post an answer

Comment: Ok what its meed swap 2.0gi its the ram broken?

Comment: No.... I am posting the answer

Comment: ok thank you ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131899/discussion-between-someone-and-mike-hadzhiev).